gcp set "Control VM access through IAM permissions" on existing vm for oslogin
In order to enable oslogin to an existing vm of gcp,I have set up enable-oslogin in project setup and user is granted as osadminlogin.
However this vm is an existing vm, no way to choose "Control VM access through IAM permissions" during the creation.
Any other way to choose this in an existing vm?
Thanks in advance
